# Merging inner-inner arrays of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
Array (        
        [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3

                )

        [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (  
                            [0] => 3
                            [1] => 4
                        )
                ) 
    )
```

What I want to do is merge together the inner arrays of [1] to give me a new array that looks something like this:

```
Array (    
         [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3

                        )
        [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                            [4] => 4
                        )
    )
```

Any tips on how I can do this please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3
    ),
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2
        ),
        1 => array(  
            0 => 3,
            1 => 4
        )
    ) 
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
    $fixedArray = array();

    foreach ($arr[$i] as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) continue;

        foreach ($value as $subKey => $subValue)
            $fixedArray[] = $subValue;
    }

    if (count($fixedArray) > 0)
        $arr[$i] = $fixedArray;
}

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

)
```

Thats one way to do it, not saying it's the best way, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, does the job!

Answer (score 1):

This the mine:

```
<?php
$multiArray = [
    0 => [
        0 =>1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 3
    ],
    1 => [
        0 => [
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2
        ],
        1 => [
            0 => 3,
            1 => 4

        ]
    ]
];

$aux = [];
foreach($multiArray as $key => $arr){
    foreach($arr as $k =>$a){
        if (is_array($a) ){
            $aux= $arr;
            break;
        }
    }
}

list($item1, $item2) = $aux;
$new = array_merge($item1, $item2);
$multiArray[1] =$new;
print_r($multiArray);
?>
```